# static library path in android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, static-libraries

I want to link static library to android NDK , I copied the libmpi.a and the include folder to the android project and here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# static library info

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:= libmpi
LOCAL_MODULE := libmpi
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuilt/libmpi.a 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuilt/include

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# wrapper info
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := androidwfpic2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libmpi 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

it compiles without errors but crashes at run time so when I tried ndk-gdb  I found that it can't seen the path to the include folder

```
Warning: workspace/AndroidWFpic2/../prebuilt/include: No such file or directory.
warning: .dynamic section for "workspace/AndroidWFpic2/obj/local/armeabi/linker" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 64 libraries, e.g. libstdc++.so.
```

I want to know how to write the path so that it can link at runtime